# Parsing raw http request from string -> Unexpected EOF

Tags: http, go, https

Given the following code I'd expect the `http.ReadRequest` to return a valid request which can then be used further. However, I get the following error message: `panic: unexpected EOF` and I don't know how I can make this work. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "net/http"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    s := `GET https://httpbin/get HTTP/1.1`

    req, err := http.ReadRequest(bufio.NewReader(strings.NewReader(s)))

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    _ = req

}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/NLsBW_Vvquw

Comment: The function returns the unexpected end of file error because the input is an incomplete request.  Append two line terminators to the data in the question to create a complete request.

Comment: Does a request always need two line endings per standard?

Comment: Yes.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_syntax